# Como realizar que el show o mostrar salgan las imagenes CKeditor

Tags: laravel

Como hacer que se vean las imagenes que pego en el formulario

me sale de esta forma...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <strong>Comunicación con el Cliente:</strong>
                        {{ $analisi->comucliente }}
                        
                    </div>
```

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Comment: Fijate si te sirve https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data